# pam_tally2 on Ubuntu Desktop 22.04LTS

Tags: 22.04

Am I missing something or has the `pam_tally2` module and binary been moved to a different package in 22.04?

The `libpam-modules` and `libpam-modules-bin` packages are installed but there is no `pam_tally2` binary or `pam_tally2.so` on the machine.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

The `pam_tally2` (and `pam_tally`) modules are no longer built and `pam_faillock` is the replacement.

From the [changelog](http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/p/pam/pam_1.4.0-11ubuntu2/changelog) for `pam` (the source package for `libpam-modules`)

```
Date: Mon, 28 Dec 2020 06:05:13 +0000
...
   * Drop pam_tally and pam_tally2 modules, which have been deprecated
     upstream in favor of pam_faillock.  Closes: #569746, LP: #772121.
```

These are the bug reports referenced in that comment

- https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=569746
- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pam/+bug/772121

The `pam_faillock` man page

- http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man8/pam_faillock.8.html

Comment: Thanks Andrew. Makes sense and i have moved it over to faillock now.

Comment: how to remove the modules? They are preventing OS upgrade. I understand they have been removed from PAM and it tells me that I need to remove the use of these 2 modules but I haven't been able to find out how to actually do that.

Answer (score 1):

If Ubuntu won't allow you to upgrade from 20.04 to 22.04 you will need to run `grep` or `find` within the `/etc/pam.d` folder and locate instances in the config files of `pam_tally` and `pam_tally2`.

For instance: `sudo find /etc/ -type f -exec grep -l -i "pam_tally" {} \;`

Simply commenting out the entries was not enough for us - we had to completely remove the lines AND any `.bak` files we created with `pam_tally` in them. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I can see the man page is available for pam_tally2 under ubuntu 22.04 jammy.
https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man8/pam_tally2.8.html