# Upgrade failing from 20.04 to 22.04 LTS

Tags: do-release-upgrade

```
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libpam-modules_1.4.0-11ubuntu2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
new libpam-modules:amd64 package pre-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
/var/cache/apt/archives/libpam-modules_1.4.0-11ubuntu2_amd64.deb
ERROR: Cannot create report: [Errno 17] File exists: '/var/crash/libpam-modules.0.crash'
Exception during pm.DoInstall():  E:Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Unfortunately there is very little actionable information here to go on. Could you [edit] your question to include whether is this on bare-metal, inside a VM, inside a Docker container, or in WSL? This will make it a bit easier to offer some specific advice 

Answer (score 0):

I met the same error message and could fix it with the following command.

```
# grep pam_tally /etc/pam.d/*
/etc/pam.d/common-auth
# mv /etc/pam.d/common-auth /etc/pam.d/common-auth.bak
# apt --fix-broken install
```

Related posts:

- [pam_tally2 on Ubuntu Desktop 22.04LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1410127/pam-tally2-on-ubuntu-desktop-22-04lts)
- https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pam/+question/706672